`systemctl reload` fails, but failed status not recognized by `systemctl is-failed`
On Ubuntu 22.04 server, I have a bash script that reloads nagios4 config. After the reload I would like to check if the service is fine
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl reload nagios4.service

if (systemctl --quiet is-failed nagios4.service); then
    echo "Bad config!"
fi

somehow it's not working, if the config is not ok, the service fails but this is not recognized by systemctl is-failed
if manually I check systemctl status nagios4
× nagios4.service - nagios4
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nagios4.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-06-05 09:20:03 CEST; 4min 27s ago


I have tried to change my script to use restart instead of reload or to run systemctl is-failed with sudo, but nothing changes.
What am I missing?

Update: reload return status is 0 even on failure
sudo systemctl reload nagios4.service
status=$?
echo $status



I wonder what's the return code of the failed reload command is.

@TomYan reload has return code 0

The reload command sends a signal to the service to reload its configuration without restarting the entire service. If the reload fails due to a bad configuration, the service might not immediately transition to a "failed" state that systemctl is-failed can detect.
One reliable way is to check the status of the service directly after the reload, rather than relying on the exit status of the reload command itself. Here’s how you can adjust your script:
#!/bin/bash

# Reload the service
sudo systemctl reload nagios4.service

# Wait a moment to ensure the service has time to fail if the config is bad
sleep 2

# Check the service status
if systemctl is-active --quiet nagios4.service; then
    echo "Reload successful!"
else
    echo "Bad config!"
fi


Thanks, so systemctl reload is kind of async. I am pretty sure that waiting 2 seconds would  be the solution in 99% of times. But in my experience waiting for an arbitrary time is risky. What if the reload takes longer?

Don’t use external scripts to check systemd state to begin with, use systemd to run scripts on certain states.
Lots of useful examples on how you can use OnFailure etc here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441575/proper-way-to-use-onfailure-in-systemd
